# STM32G031 Documentation Error on NVIC Priority Register Addresses?

Tags: stm32, documentation, interrupt

I am coding an STM32G031F8P6.    I want to set some interrupt priority values.  I am looking at the programming manual, PM0223.    In section 4.2 (page 82) Table 25 says that the priority registers NVIC_IPR0-7 are 0xE000E400-0xE000E4EF.    That doesn't make sense, as it implies a block 240 bytes long.   This block should be 32 bytes long.    There is no updated version of this document, nor is there an errata listing for this.  Are the priority registers the first 8 words (32 bytes) in this block, or evenly distributed in the 240 byte block?   (cross posted to ST Community site as well).

Answer (score 1):

Somebody (Jan Waclawek) in the ST Community forum pointed out that this error doesn't originate from ST, but was copied in their documentation from the same error in the ARM documentation.
They also showed some updated ARM docs that said that the addresses are (as should be expected) in the first 8 words, thus 0xE000E400-0xE000E41F.
Thanks Jan!